# how to refresh parent page when I use SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I open a dialog (let's say **DialogA.aspx**) from my page (**PageA.aspx**) using this

```
function OpenCustomDialog(dialogUrl, dialogWidth, dialogHeight, dialogTitle, dialogAllowMaximize, dialogShowClose) {

    var options = {
        url: dialogUrl,
        allowMaximize: dialogAllowMaximize,
        showClose: dialogShowClose,
        width: dialogWidth,
        height: dialogHeight,
        title: dialogTitle,
        dialogReturnValueCallback: Function.createDelegate(null, CloseCallback3)
    };
    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

From that Dialog, I try to open another pop up using this

function OpenPopupInDialog(dialogUrl, dialogWidth, dialogHeight) {

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(dialogUrl, null, dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
```

}

But when I close the popup, I want to refresh the **DialogA.aspx**.

How can I do it ?

btw, I am still new to SharePoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can add implement your own close callback and refresh page from there.

Refer to this link tor more details: http://antoniolanaro.blogspot.com/2011/04/open-sharepoint-2010-modal-dialog-and.html.

**Update:**
According to [documentation of SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff410825.aspx), the second parameter is a callback to a function to be invoked when the dialog is closed.
I suppose you can try to do it like this:

- on the page you want to refresh (**DialogA.aspx** in this case) you can add a function refreshing the page, i.e.

  ```
  function CustomPageRefresh(dialogResult, returnValue) {
      document.location.reload(); //or another method you need to refresh the page in your case
  }
  ```
- on the same page, change the `OpenPopupInDialog` to something like this:

  ```
  function OpenPopupInDialog(dialogUrl, dialogWidth, dialogHeight) {
      SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage(dialogUrl, CustomPageRefresh, dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
  }
  ```

Comment: I still can't refresh the **DialogA** page which is also a dialog.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and will let you know the result.